# Is it "Er ist berühmt in der ganzen Welt." or "Er ist in der ganzen Welt berühmt."?

Tags: sentence-structure

How do we know the order of the words to build a german sentence?

Comment: Your first question: The second sentence is correct. Your second question is very difficult to answer. There are many rules in German language because the structure of the sentences is rather complicated.

Comment: Actually, both sentences are valid.

Comment: Not sure if this is a regional issue, but even though "**in** der ganzen Welt" is not wrong, to me the more natural wording would be "**auf** der ganzen Welt"

Answer (score 7):

> **Er** ist in der ganzen Welt *berühmt*.
>
> **Er** ist berühmt *in der ganzen Welt*.

Both sentences are valid. The difference in word order in this case is all about emphasis. In German sentences, the first item has most emphasis, the last item second most. The other valid permutations are:

> **Berühmt** ist er *in der ganzen Welt*.
>
> **Berühmt** ist in der ganzen Welt *nur er*. *(lonely pronouns at the end sound a bit strange.)*
>
> **In der ganzen Welt** ist er *berühmt*.
>
> <s>**In der ganzen Welt** ist berühmt er.</s> *(this is the only one hopelessly wrong.)*

As you can see, the only thing stable in the order of sentence parts is the predicate **ist**. It's V2 word order —the main part of the predicate verb comes second in declarative sentences—, the most important rule of German word ordering. All other things are pretty flexible.

Comment: This answer is correct. But you might want to add that the first two (Er ist...) use the default word order; in the others, part of the sentence has been extrapositioned to give it more emphasis.

Comment: The emphasized parts are **bold** resp. *italic* in my answers.